# Two dimensional scrolling... a suggestion that needs feedback

Tags: android, scroll

While spending a copious amount of time googling for a relatively simple solution to my problem I found this as a solution for two-dimensional scrolling.  I have a a horizontalscrollview nested in a scrollview.  I fiddled with this in a few ways and was unsuccessful in making anything functional.  Does anyone have any ideas on how to make a concept like this work?

```
Scrollview scrollY = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollY);
LinearLayout scrollYChild = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.scrollYChild);

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    scrollYChild.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    scrollY.onTouchEvent(event);
    return true;
}
```

I have also found this: http://blog.gorges.us/2010/06/android-two-dimensional-scrollview/ but I'm don't understand at all how to implement such a long piece of code properly.

It doesn't make much sense to me that two-dimensional scrolling is inherent in a webview but nonexistent elsewhere... Any and all help is appreciated.

Edit:  How exactly does this work when zoomed in on an image in the gallery.  Surely there has to be a way to implement that same functionality here.

Comment: Now I notice that the link provided has code that "only supports vertical scrolling"... waste of time.  Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im not sure about the blog you have posted, this was my solution:

```
/**
 * This class disables Y-motion on touch event.
 * It should only be used as parent class of HorizontalScrollView
 */
public class ParentScrollView extends ScrollView {
    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
    View.OnTouchListener mGestureListener;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public ParentScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new YScrollDetector());
        setFadingEdgeLength(0);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if( mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev)&super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev)){
            return true;
        }else{

            return false;
        }
    }

    // Return false if we're scrolling in the x direction  
    class YScrollDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
            if(Math.abs(distanceY) > Math.abs(distanceX)) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

XML:

```
    <com.example.Views.ParentScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/tlDBtable"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </com.example.Views.ParentScrollView>
```

Basically the parent scrollview which only scrolls veritcal will be disabled because you will use a new custom class. Then you put a HScrollview within the scroll view. The Parentscroll view will pass the touch even if its not vertical to the horiszontalscroll view which makes it 2D scrolling effect.

Comment: I have yet to do this at all.  I assume that I make a new java file with this and add the bottom to my xml layout.  If this is true, do I need to add anything to my manifest, or just make a new javaproject?

Comment: You will need basic understanding of Custom view classes which is documented in offical site. but for this problem, You create the class i provided in your package then use the xml which must match your package name.

Comment: I think I understand.  Looking at this, the only other thing I need to know is, what goes in the context and attrs for ParentScrollView()?

Comment: You do not need it to change anything in the source class, context atrrs is provided in the xml which is inflated in activity which provides context.

Comment: Fantastic.  Thanks so much for your patience!

Comment: I believe I did everything I was supposed to.  But, in my xml file I get an error: error parsing XML - unbound prefix.  What could be causing this error?

Comment: As I have stated before , you will need basic understanding of custom views, the xml is only code snippt, you have to add to your main layout that is using in your activity. But the java source code you will not need to modify anything. use as it is.

Comment: This is the xml i have:
<com.example.Views.ParentScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/Pscrollview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="0dp" >
 
 <HorizontalScrollView....
it goes on for a while... I only have the single error at the top.  I suppose I'll keep reading.
And, yes, that is indeed the name of my package... i'm just playing around in a "test" application right now

Comment: com.example.Views.ParentScrollView <-- change all these to where YOUR actual class is located.

Comment: that is where they are o.O  haha i had an extra ">" on the very end of the xml... oh boy

Comment: I added the class... put all the code together correctly.  I tried to run the program and got a "program failed to load error.  I debugged the application and took a look at logcat.  I have a java.io.FileNotFoundException: /dev/kmsg (Permission Denied).  Any idea what might be causing this error?

Comment: This isn't related to this question, because it doesn't deal with `File`. You are missing a permission. You should be able to search this yourself.

Comment: Thanks for this solution with 2D scrolling, however it's not really possible to scroll diagonally with this implementation. Using this I can either scroll horizontally or vertically, but not both at the same time. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Perfect Solution, can you provide solution for Diagonal scroll?