# Is it possible to display original image in android without fit to device views?

Tags: android, image, imageview, image-scaling

I have an Image of size 1000px*1200px and i want it to be displayed without being scaled!.

I have  searched in stackover flow and google i am not getting good one.

I want full image without scaled,
I have tried like this

**Step1:-**

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/image"
                />
```

**Step2:-**

I have tried with scaleType also
add a scaleType to your ImageView

```
 <ImageView
    android:scaleType="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/image" />
```

But this is also not working,

In sclate type i have tried with all possible properties (matrix,fitXY like this).

is there any possibility there for doing to dispaly original image in android?

Plz help me on this

Comment: Have you try with store that image in drawable-nodpi and than set in imageview?

Comment: try android:scaleType="center" it may help you.

Comment: @Ravi i have already tried scaletype=center,but not working

Comment: Can u show some snap, what do u want actually ?

Comment: @keshav i want full image actual image 1000*1200 size,so i want that image in device also with auto scrolls.

Comment: Try a webview. It handles scrolling automatically, which is nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many trails i have find a solution for above question.

Here is the code:

**MainActivity:-**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
   }
}
```

**activity_main.xml:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <HorizontalScrollView android:id="@+id/HorizontalScrollView01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageview"
            android:src="@drawable/desert"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true">
        </ImageView>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

This is working perfectly for my requirement.

Hope this helps to others.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this approach,first get image from drawable and create a bitmap of it.Then get width and height of bitmap, resize your image view and then display image in it.It will create imageview with your original image size.

See below code  -

```
BitmapDrawable bitmap = (BitmapDrawable) this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
int bitmapHeight= bitmap .getBitmap().getHeight();
int bitmapWidth = bitmap .getBitmap().getWidth();
```

Now you have dimension of your original image.
Re-size image view -

```
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);
    imageView.getLayoutParams().height = bitmapHeight;
    imageView.getLayoutParams().width = bitmapWidth;
```

and in last step set bitmap to your image view -

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Hope it will help you.

**EDITED**

Use below code after resize image view -

```
replace - `imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);`
```

by

```
           imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
```

Comment: What about the scroll?

Comment: which scroll??Explain it?

Comment: :) .Check my answer. He'll need to handle the image scroll if needed on devices which have screens smaller than the image

Comment: getDrawable() is depricated,so it shows error in setImageBitmap().

Comment: No, it is not depricated.What error you getting,Please share the error log.

Comment: Error:(31, 18) error: method setImageBitmap in class ImageView cannot be applied to given types;
required: Bitmap
found: BitmapDrawable
reason: actual argument BitmapDrawable cannot be converted to Bitmap by method invocation conversion

Comment: what is this R.drawable.icon

Comment: Ok, then after re-sizing image view instead of setting bitmap set image from draw-able in it. Check my updated answer.

Comment: R.drawable.icon  - icon is image that you want to display from drawable folder.

Comment: @Ravi it shows same like scaleType=fitXY, There is no change.

Comment: this is also not satisfy my requirement

Answer (score 0):

By your comments， I think what you need is a library like [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView).Hope it can help you

Answer (score 0):

Although I would highly condemn such UX but whatever works for you.

1) Use the following link to make a two dimensional scroll. 
[Two dimensional scrolling... a suggestion that needs feedback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19411518/two-dimensional-scrolling-a-suggestion-that-needs-feedback)

2) Add an imageview to the same and set your image dimensions for the imageview in px at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i understand your question is that u want natural size of image without ImageView tag modifying it. This worked for me

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/image_here"
    android:orientation="horizontal|vertical"/>
```

[image: Thats my image behind steve jobs. fits perfectly as i wanted with height of 200dp]

let me know in the comments.

Comment: how this is possible?

Comment: worked for me. The only thing for me was if i used ImageView and width be match_parent, the image would be displayed in middle of activity leaving blank space bwtween app bar and image. by using LinearLayout i could do what i wanted. you can try this out and see if it fits your requirment.

Comment: nothing was required for me in the activity. i will edit the answer with a screenshot of my activity

Comment: Thats my image(behind steve jobs) using LinearLayout

Comment: This would definetely not work as the max width of the iamge would still be that of the screen and not its own

Answer (score 0):

Make your image layout width and height to wrap content. Make scaleType centre. Check your device width and height through device manager then give image height and width in %

Comment: i don't want to give static height and width,i want dynamically scroll the image .

Comment: just suggesting okay.You can give your image width 90% by using (window manager)and height as usual (wrap content) inside scrollView.