# Why my HorizontalScrollView scrolls vertically?

Tags: android, layout

I have `TextView` in `HorizontalScrollView` and i want to make text scrollable, but Horizontally. I don`t know why but this textview can be scrolled only in vertical direction

```
     <HorizontalScrollView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       >
    <TextView
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/equation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:text="Empty"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"/>

   </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Solution I've used. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19411518/two-dimensional-scrolling-a-suggestion-that-needs-feedback/19411644#19411644

Answer (score 1):

OK I have solved it. The Problem was that my `HorizontalScrollView` was in `LinearLayout` with `vertical` orientation. So I have created new `LinearLayout` with `horizontal` orientation and put in in `LinearLayout` with `vertical` orientation.
That worked for me.

Comment: In my case inside a HorizontalScrollView I had a vertical layout! I changed it to horizontal, thanks.