# Concurrent horizontal and vertical scrolling of a large image

Tags: android, scrollview, angular2-nativescript

How can I achieve concurrent horizontal and vertical scrolling of a large image in Angular2 Nativescript (focusing on Android)?

Using nested ScrollViews allows user to scroll in only one direction at a time - I want to scroll diagonally, but can't.

```
<ScrollView orientation="horizontal">
    <ScrollView> 
        <image src="~/img/largeimage.png" stretch="none"></image>
    </ScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19411518/two-dimensional-scrolling-a-suggestion-that-needs-feedback) question. Or you can use [BigImageViewer](https://github.com/Piasy/BigImageViewer) library which supports pan and zoom, with very little memory usage and full featured image loading choices

Comment: I am interested in zoom as well so BigImageViewer sounds great, but I am having trouble figuring out how to add and use a Java library like BIV with my Angular Nativescript project.  The BIV documentation mentions Fresco, which I was able to add a nativescript version of via NPM, but this was slower than ScrollView.  Do you think BIV might offer better performance, and if so how would I add and use it with Nativescript?

Comment: Sorry i didn't see the 'angular2-nativescript' tag before. I thought you need it on android. Anyways, i don't know how to use it in angular nativescript but i found a good tutorial [here](https://egghead.io/lessons/angular-2-use-an-android-library-in-nativescript-for-angular-using-java-apis) which teaches how to use an Android library in NativeScript for Angular using Java apis.

Comment: And i think it might offer better performance because it [claims](https://github.com/Piasy/BigImageViewer#why-another-big-image-viewer) so.